# Show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot \left(\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{itx} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2 } dx \right) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}$

Tags: integration, analysis

I am struggling to show that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot \left(\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{itx} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2 } dx \right) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}$$

In the same paper we defined  $$F(t):=\left(\int_0^t e^{-x^2}\right)^2 \quad \text{ and} \quad  G(t):=\left( \int _0^1\frac{e^{-t^2(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2} \right)$$

I showed that both functions are differentiable with
 $$F'= 2e^{-t^2} \cdot \int_0^t e^{-x^2}$$ $$G' = -2te^{-t^2} \cdot \int_0^1 e^{-x^2t^2}$$

It follows that $F' + G' = 0$ and $F + G = \frac{\pi}{4}$

With that I showed that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{\pi}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think what you wish to prove is true. Since the integral is wrt $x$, the $e^{-\frac12 t^2}$ can be factored out, leaving $$\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itx} \, dx=1$$ But the LHS is divergent for ant $t$.

Comment: Thank you for noticing. I made an error instead of $e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2 }$ i wrote $e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2 }$

Comment: One way is to note that both sides satisfy the ODE $u' + tu = 0$, and consequently must be constant multiples of each other and then determine the constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By completing the square, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac12t^2+itx}\,dt&=e^{-\frac12 x^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac12\left(t-ix\right)^2}\,dt\\\\
&=e^{-\frac12 x^2}\int_{-\infty-ix}^{\infty-ix} e^{-\frac12 t^2}\,dt\\\\
\end{align}$$

Then, invoking Cauchy's Integral Theorem, we can deform the contour back onto the real line, which reveals

$$\int_{-\infty-ix}^{\infty-ix} e^{-\frac12 t^2}\,dt=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac12 t^2}\,dt=\sqrt {2\pi}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac12t^2+itx}\,dt=e^{-\frac12 x^2}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: I've provided a second solution that forgoes CIT and relies instead on Feynman's trick.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way forward that relies on Feyman's trick.

Let $f$ be defined by the integral of interest

$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac12 t^2}e^{itx}\,dt$$

Differentiating under the integral yields

$$f'(x) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty ite^{-\frac12 t^2}e^{itx}\,dt$$

Integrating by parts with $u=ie^{itx}$ and $v=-e^{-\frac12 t^2}$ reveals

$$f'(x)=-xf(x)$$

from which it is easy to see that $f(x)=Ae^{-\frac12 x^2}$.  Since $f(0)=\sqrt{2\pi}$, we find that $A=\sqrt{2\pi}$ and

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac12 t^2}e^{itx}\,dt=e^{-\frac12x^2}$$

as expected!

Comment: Thats neat thank you alot

Comment: You're welcome!  Pleased to hear.